# Run if statement in loop only once

Tags: loops

Just curious if its possible.
Consider follwing code:

```
boolean firstRow = true;

while{row = result.next())
{
    if(firstRow)
    {
        firstRow = false;
        //do some setup 
    }

    //do stuff
}
```

Its pseudo-code and question is general not about some specific programming language.

My question: is it possible to write code that behaves exactly same but without using additional variable (in this case "firstRow"). In FOR loop its possible to check counter variable value but lets leave FOR loops out of this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, do your setup before you start the loop and change it to a do..while.  For example:

```
if (row = result.next()) {
  //do some setup 
  do {
    //do stuff
  } while (row = result.next());   
}
```

Comment: If possible, i'd like to do it inside loop.

Comment: Without another variable to keep track, I don't think that's possible.  You need some way to differentiate state and - without knowning anything else about your data - a variable (boolean, counter, whatever) is probably the only way to do that.  Given that you distinguished "setup" from "stuff", it's not obvious to me **why** you would want to do it that way.

Comment: @Keios: Do you have a good practical reason? "I'd *like* to do it this way" is not a valid argument to reject a simpler solution.

Comment: Hmmm. This is functionally equivalent to mine. I guess the only difference is I trade separating the check and the assignment for not having to nest the entire loop in an `if` check. Anyway, people who give the same answer as me get an automatic +1 (for obvious genius :-) )

Comment: Only reason is that I get parameters for setup from that "row" variable.

Comment: @Keois: So, since the if condition (above) populates "row", isn't that sufficient?

Comment: @delnan - I'm looping over hundreds of objects and doing a few things with them, plus there's a few extra things I want to do with a single special object that's somewhere in the group but I don't know where in advance. So I'm wondering how I can make sure my condition stops evaluating once that special object in the group has been found, without extra variables.

Comment: It seems to me that the compiled code would have to be capable of modifying itself... is that at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(row = result.next())
{
    //do some setup
    while(row) 
    {
        //do stuff
        row = result.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some options. The first would be to move the "setup" code outside the loop. If you don't care that this would cause the setup to happen even when you never iterate at all, that is probably the best option. If you *do* care about that, you could add the loop condition to the if check.

```
if(row = result.next())
{
    //do some setup 
}
for (;row;row=result.next()) 
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Another would be to make your loop as simple as possible, and trust your compiler's optimizer to do the "unrolling" described above. It probably will, if you set the optimization options high enough.